# Get culture by country name

Tags: vb.net

I have only the country name and I need the Culture. I tried by region:

```
Dim region As New RegionInfo("USA")
```

Is there a way to get Culture Info by country name only?

Comment: You will likely have to build a lookup of some sort, mapping ISO country names to `CultureInfo` codes.

Comment: @TimSchmelter I tried that, but in some cases it returns more than one culture.

Comment: @Cory Thanks, thought it would be more elegant(.Net) answer :-)

Comment: @user1249350: well, a region or country can have multiple cultures. So you have to pick one, for example with `FirstOrDefault`.

Comment: @TimSchmelter yep - but than it's not accurate in some of the cases

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could this class i've created only just (so not really tested):

```
public class CountryCultureInfo
{ 
    static CountryCultureInfo()
    {
        countryCultures = new Dictionary<string, HashSet<CultureInfo>>(StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);
        foreach (CultureInfo culture in CultureInfo.GetCultures(CultureTypes.SpecificCultures))
        {
            RegionInfo region = new RegionInfo(culture.Name);
            HashSet<CultureInfo> cultures;
            if (!countryCultures.TryGetValue(region.ThreeLetterISORegionName, out cultures))
                cultures = new HashSet<CultureInfo>();
            cultures.Add(culture);
            countryCultures[region.ThreeLetterISORegionName] = cultures;
        }
    }

    private static Dictionary<string, HashSet<CultureInfo>> countryCultures;

    public static HashSet<CultureInfo> GetCultures(string threeLetterISORegionName)
    {
        HashSet<CultureInfo> cultures;
        countryCultures.TryGetValue(threeLetterISORegionName, out cultures);
        return cultures;
    }
}
```

If you want to get all cultures in the USA:

```
var allCulturesInUSA = CountryCultureInfo.GetCultures("USA"); // en-US, es-US
```

or in brasil:

```
var allCulturesInBrasil = CountryCultureInfo.GetCultures("BRA"); // pt-BR
```

**Edit**: sorry, here's the VB.NET version (overlooked the tag):

```
Public Class CountryCultureInfo
    Shared Sub New()
        countryCultures = New Dictionary(Of String, HashSet(Of CultureInfo))(StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)
        For Each culture As CultureInfo In CultureInfo.GetCultures(CultureTypes.SpecificCultures)
            Dim region As New RegionInfo(culture.Name)
            Dim cultures As HashSet(Of CultureInfo) = Nothing
            If Not countryCultures.TryGetValue(region.ThreeLetterISORegionName, cultures) Then
                cultures = New HashSet(Of CultureInfo)()
            End If
            cultures.Add(culture)
            countryCultures(region.ThreeLetterISORegionName) = cultures
        Next
    End Sub

    Private Shared countryCultures As Dictionary(Of String, HashSet(Of CultureInfo))

    Public Shared Function GetCultures(threeLetterISORegionName As String) As HashSet(Of CultureInfo)
        Dim cultures As HashSet(Of CultureInfo) = Nothing
        countryCultures.TryGetValue(threeLetterISORegionName, cultures)
        Return cultures
    End Function
End Class
```

Comment: Thank you, working nice (some minor changes for vb :-) )

Comment: @user1249350: whoops, sorry, overlooked the VB tag. Edited my answer.